# Update ClockWorkMod

Tags: updates, clockworkmod-recovery

I have flashed my phone with Odin loading hardcore's Kernel with the ClockworkMod Recovery 2.5.

How can I know which is the latest version of ClockworkMod and how can it be updated, please?
I saw there is a Play Store app for ClockworkMod but I am unsure of how it differs from the one installed using Odin.

Thank you.

Comment: What's your phone model?

Comment: It's a Samsung Galaxy S.

Comment: @Francisc am surprised you left out the obvious information relating to handset despite you having 1 gold star, 5 silver and 20 bronze... and being on this for more than 2+years ... :o xD

Comment: Yeah, I didn't think that updating something already installed would require knowledge of the model. Here, have my gold badge. Give it to someone more deserving.

Comment: That's bollocks, you don't build up 850+ reps for nothing! :P

I thought it must've been an oversight from your part. Anyway, happy to help buddy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download the latest CWM recovery available for your phone from [here](http://download2.clockworkmod.com/recoveries/recovery-clockwork-2.5.1.2-galaxys.zip), put it in the root of your sd card, reboot into recovery (power off and press and hold some key combo, that depends on your phone; Google for instructions) and flash it.

You can also try [TWRP](http://teamw.in/twrp_view_all_devices), another popular custom recovery.

Let me know if you need any clarification!

Comment: Sumesh, I might want to borrow your crystal ball -- how do you tell he's got a Galaxy? Couldn't "Odin" mean any Samsung device? Or does the variant you linked work for all Samsung devices? Just asking, before it might do harm flashing the wrong one ;)

Comment: Izzy: He asked in the comments for the question.

Comment: Sumesh: Thank you. Flashing means wiping the phone, right?

Comment: Also, how can I keep track of when new versions of ClockworkMod appear? There doesn't seem to be an official website for that.

Comment: @Francisc - The Clockworkmod team posts notices about updates on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/ClockworkMod), [Google+](https://plus.google.com/u/0/112476065271141473049), and [Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/ClockworkMod)

Comment: @Francisc - Flashing just the recovery won't wipe anything.

Comment: No wipe/factory reset! 

Reboot into recovery, hit install update zip from sd card (or similar, depends on your present recovery) and select the zip file you downloaded and placed on sdcard. Then reboot.

As for keeping track of new versions of CWM, I suggest FB/Twitter like Compro01 suggested. 

Or buy ROM Manager - a bit steep at $6 but you'd be supporting a dev who works full time on these stuff (Koush).